# How to receive large interbusiness payments

Tags: salary

My personal company is about to make ou
r first sale of a large enterprise software we have developed to a client. We are based approximately 1000 miles away from the company we are selling to. We are currently registered as an LLC in our state and hold a local operating permit. We have a bank account open for the business with a respectable bank.

The software we are selling values between $20,000 and $50,000.
Upon purchase we will be sending an employee to the location to setup the software, servers, and phones (if needed) for the company and offering training and support for a few days (at high cost for us).

The problem arises with payment:

What is the most professional however most secure way for us to request payment?
Do we request payment to our agent when they arrive? or before we schedule someone to go to their headquarters?

Do we request Check, Secured check (Cashiers/certified check), money order, or direct wire transfer; I assume cash would be unprofessional.

Comment: Wire transfer. But, this question is off-topic here.

Comment: I was trying to find an exchange that looked directed to finances or business and this seemed the most similar

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about business banking.  It might be on topic for Startups or Money but I'm not sure.

Comment: I agree with @JustinCave, startups would be a better place for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the purchasing company is of any size they will have likely raised a purchase order, which you will invoice to their accounts payable dept, they will then make the payment via the agreed method.

I don't think you'll be getting payment whilst you are on site, they'll usually have 30 days, to allow for issues etc.